# Dynamic allocation of matrix makes program not respond

Tags: c++, dynamic, matrix, allocation

I've looked through most of the questions already posted, and can't seem to find a fix :<

Here's my issue. I have the following class for graphs (only included relevant code):

```
class Graph{
    protected:
    int **A;
    int n;
    public:
    Graph(){
        A=NULL; 
        n=0;};
    ~Graph(){
        int i;
        if(n)
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            delete [] A[i];
        delete A;
        n=0;};
    // Methods
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&,Graph&);
    friend void operator>>(fstream,Graph&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,Graph&);
    friend void operator<<(fstream,Graph&);
    int GetA(int i,int j){
        return A[i][j];}
    int Getn(){
        return n;}
    void Setn(int k){
        n=k;}
    void SetA(int i,int j,int k){
        A[i][j]=k;}
    void AllocA();
};
```

This is what main does until getting the error:

```
int main(){
    Graph graphA;
    "input.txt">>graphA;
}
```

"input.txt" contains :

```
9
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The overloaded (file)>> friend :

```
void operator>>(char *fis_in,Graph &graph){
        int k,x;
        ifstream fin(fis_in);
        fin>>k;
        graph.Setn(k);
        graph.AllocA();
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<k;i++)
            for(j=0;j<k;j++){
                fin>>x;
                graph.SetA(i,j,x);}
        cls;        // #define cls system("cls"), just for convenience
        cout<<"Done !";
        delay(1);   // Irrelevant, just a 1 second delay
        fin.close();
    }
```

And finally, the method that gives the error, AllocA:

```
void Graph::AllocA(){
    int i;
    *A = new int[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        A[i] = new int[n];}
```

More explicitly, it gets stuck on *A = new int[n];

I've checked the n, it was read from the file and had the value 9 like it was supposed to.. I've also tried manually setting it to 9 just in case... I really don't know what the issue is.. I've done dynamic allocation of matrixes before but this has never happened.. Hope the post is readable.

Comment: I've said in the post that n is 9 as it is supposed to be. Yes.

Comment: You forgot to allocate `A`. And that's a very unconventional  `>>` operator.

Comment: That's what AllocA() is supposed to do... the >> operator isn't the issue. it's working with a static matrix.

Comment: Shoudnt the line in Alloca be *A = new int*[n];

Comment: Doing that returns error: cannot convert 'int**' to 'int*' in assignment|

Comment: @Radvo `*A = new int [n]` is equivalent to `A[0] = new int [n]`. You want `A = new int* [n]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't dereference a pointer until it points to something. `A` is never initialized, but then you do this:

```
*A = new int[n];
```

This (`*A`) is dereferencing. You need to set `A` to point to something before you dereference it.